# UWP - How to get website contents and store them in a string?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to make an app, that can read a text from a website and store it in a string.
For example my app could open [this random generator website](https://www.random.org/strings/?num=10&len=10&digits=on&unique=on&format=html&rnd=new), which would generate a random number string and then my program would read it and store it in a string.
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get your goal but you may get the whole HTML page and parse it as you wish:

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var htmlString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use that, and precise the encoding :

```
string text = null;
using (WebResponse response = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse())
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
   {
      text = reader.ReadToEnd();
      reader.Close();
   }
   response.Close();
 }
```